# Matrix Representation of Second Degree Linear Recurrence Equations

Tags: c++, math, matrix, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

I can calculate the Matrix representation of **first degree** Linear recurrence equations. And I  calculate for higher order by using **fast matrix exponentiation**. I learnt this from this tutorial
http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/

But I am facing problem in calculating the matrix representation of **Second Degree** Linear recurrence equations. For example -

```
S(n) = a * (S(n - 1))^2 + b * S(n - 1) + c
where S(0) = d
```

Can you help me to figure out the matrix representation of the above equation or give me some insights? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There ain't any matrix representations. The dependence of quadratic iteration from its initial point S(0) can be visualized in the Julia fractal, and the dependence of the shape of the Julia fractal from its coefficients (a,b,c) is classified by the Mandelbrot or apple-man fractal. I recently wrote down how one gets from the general quadratic iteration to the normalized form on math.SE, http://math.stackexchange.com/a/704796/115115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is polynomial of second degree. The well-known recurrence

```
 x_(n+1) = (x_n)^2 + c
```

that is often called the [*quadratic map*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html) is not in general solvable in closed form. Quadratic iteration

```
x_(n+1) = a (x_n)^2 + b x_n + c
```

is iteration of the Mandelbrot fractals.
This is the real version of the complex map defining the [Mandelbrot set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html).